# ListView com uma coluna vazia e editável

Tags: c#, listview, wpf, combobox, linq-to-sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Pessoal queria ter células vazias e editáveis numa coluna de numa ListView que puxa do Banco de Dados SQL Server informações para meu projeto. Para puxar a informações uso o LINQ e consigo listar todos os dados que quero. A ideia é: quando carregada essa lista o usuário pudesse editar as células de uma nova coluna (Quantidade), as informações que serão inseridas nessas células (números inteiros) servirão para outros cálculos no projeto.

No código XMAL  não estou conseguindo deixar os valores vazios...Dessa forma está retornando o caminho da classe.

Quem puder ajudar ficarei bastante grato!!

Anexei uma imagem para facilitar a dúvida...É na coluna Quantidade que as células precisam está vazias e editáveis para o usuário. Ela não faz parte do banco SQL, exibo apenas para o usuário inserir os dados.

- **Código XMAL:**

  ```
   <ListView x:Name="listView_tabMaqPrda_ApontaPrd" Margin="99,117,915,583" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
             SelectionMode="Single">                              

      <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Código" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CodigoParada}"/>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Descrição da Parada" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DescricaoParada}"/>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Tempo(min)" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TempoParada}"/>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo de Parada" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TipoParada}"/>
              <GridViewColumn Header="Quantidade" Width="Auto" />
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
  ```

**Classe LINQ:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TRSSystem.AcessoDados
{
    public class tabMaquinaParadaAcesso
    {
//Consultar pela MAQUINA no Banco pela estrutura LINQ TO SQL Server
        public static List<tabMaquinaParada> Consultar_OnlyMaquina(string pMaquina, string pTipo)
        {
            TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext oDB = new TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext();
            List<tabMaquinaParada> aMaquina = (from Selecao in oDB.tabMaquinaParadas where Selecao.Maquina == pMaquina && Selecao.Sacaria == pTipo select Selecao).ToList<tabMaquinaParada>();
            return aMaquina;

        }

    }
}
```

**Evento LostFocus de um Combox, quando se carrega a lista:**

```
private void CarregarParadas_ApontaPrd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listView_tabMaqPrda_ApontaPrd.ItemsSource = TRSSystem.AcessoDados.tabMaquinaParadaAcesso.Consultar_OnlyMaquina(CmBox_MaquinaApontaPrd.Text, CmBox_TipoApontaPrd.Text);

        }catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de Compilação, contacte o Administrador do Sistema." + error, "Erro de Compilação", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui dessa forma pessoal...

**XMAL:**

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Quantidade" Width="Auto">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Quantidade}" Width="30" MaxLength="2" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" 
                     FontFamily="Calibri" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Fonte:
[Populating ComboBox inside ListView in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089843/populating-combobox-inside-listview-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Da mesma forma como declaraste as propriedades codigoParada, descricaoParada e tempoParada na sua classe tabMaquinaParada, adicione mais uma propriedade "qualidade", mas sem valores e adicione o binding no código da coluna qualidade para fazer desaparecer o nome da classe, assim:

Comment: Boa noite, amigo. Assim?

Comment: <GridViewColumn Header="Quantidade" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantidade}"/>

Comment: Assim funcionou...Ou seja, retorna vazio. Pós agora preciso saber como tornar as células dessa coluna editáveis.

Comment: Exatamente assim. Agora, quanto a tornar a coluna editavel, sugiro que uses um Datagrid, porque o ListView foi desenvolvido apenas com o objectivo de apresentar dados, não editar, esse é o objectivo do DataGrid (Visualisar e manipular dados), ou crie um TextBox com o binding setando a propriedade do ListView que pretendes alterar.

Comment: Obrigado...Mudei para DataGrid...Porém quando digito os valores nas células que pretendo editar após sair dela os que foi digitado some...Como faço para deixar os dados que estão sendo editados visíveis?

Comment: Não faço ideia do que está a acontecer contigo, mas acho que encontrarás outras perguntas que podem responder a tua questão. Qualquer outra dúvida é só perguntar. Não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como respondida. ;)

Comment: Amigo...Se puder ajudar...http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130745/datagrid-editando-dados-apenas-n%C3%BAmeros-e-calculando-seu-valores-wpf-c-co