# Como editar dados (apenas números) e calcular seus valores numa DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Preciso que uma coluna do DataGrid receba dos usuários apenas números nas linhas (células) e que após click no botão seja realizados cálculos de multiplicação entre células de uma mesma linha e colunas diferentes. O DataGrid é populado como segue a classe abaixo através da ferramenta LINQ...A coluna dos usuários é a "Nº Paradas", ela precisa ser multiplicada pela coluna "Tempo (min)".

*Porém os valores que o usuário digita nas células não permanecem nelas*, *o que é digitado está sumindo*. Assim que sai da célula o valor é apagado, porquê?

E quanto a lógica do cálculo estou apenas conseguindo somar as células de uma coluna.

Quem puder ajudar agradeço. Abaixo ponho a sequência dos comandos...

**Classe LINQ:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TRSSystem.AcessoDados
{
    public class tabMaquinaParadaAcesso
    {
//Consultar pela MAQUINA no Banco pela estrutura LINQ TO SQL Server
        public static List<tabMaquinaParada> Consultar_OnlyMaquina(string pMaquina, string pTipo)
        {
            TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext oDB = new TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext();
            List<tabMaquinaParada> aMaquina = (from Selecao in oDB.tabMaquinaParadas where Selecao.Maquina == pMaquina && Selecao.Sacaria == pTipo select Selecao).ToList<tabMaquinaParada>();
            return aMaquina;

        }

    }
}
```

**XMAL:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="103" Width="577" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" SelectionUnit="Cell" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Código" Width="Auto" Binding={Binding CodigoParada}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrição da Parada" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding DescricaoParada}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tempo (min)" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding TempoParada}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding TipoParada}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nº Paradas" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" FontFamily="Calibri"> 
                                   <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="2"/>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                </DataGrid>
```

**Evento LostFocus de um Combox, quando se carrega a lista:**

```
private void CarregarParadas_ApontaPrd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd.ItemsSource = TRSSystem.AcessoDados.tabMaquinaParadaAcesso.Consultar_OnlyMaquina(CmBox_MaquinaApontaPrd.Text, CmBox_TipoApontaPrd.Text);
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro de Compilação, contacte o Administrador do Sistema." + error, "Erro de Compilação", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }


        }
```

**Evento PreviewTextInput - Receber apenas Inteiros**

```
private void SomenteInt_ListViewPrdPadrao_ApontaPrd(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
```

**Botão do Cálculo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para multiplicar os valores da coluna Tempo pelo Nº Paradas?

```
//Aqui apenas Soma os valores de uma coluna apenas:
 private void CalcularTempoEfetivo_ApontPrd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int somarColuna = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                tabMaquinaParada Dados = (tabMaquinaParada)dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd.Items[i];

                somarColuna = somarColuna + Dados.TempoParada;

            }

            txtTempoEfetivo_ApontaPrd.Text = Convert.ToString(somarColuna);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Problema é que você precisa fazer o binding com uma propriedade.

Como você está utilizando uma classe Linq crie uma coluna na tabela `tabMaquinaParada` apenas para o sistema aceitar este novo campo.*

> - Esta operação não é a melhor.

**Tabela**

Crie o campo `NroParada` como inteiro;

**Desing**

No desing da classe `TRSSystemDataClasses` inclua o novo campo.

**Datagrid**

E no `datagrid` do numero de paradas faz o binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Nº Paradas" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" FontFamily="Calibri" Binding="{Binding NroParada}">...</DataGridTextColumn >
```

**Calcular**

E com isso você acaba resolvendo a sua 2 pergunta:

```
    private void CalcularTempoEfetivo_ApontPrd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        int somarColuna = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd.Items.Count-1; i++)
        {

            tabMaquinaParada Dados = (tabMaquinaParada)dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd.Items[i];

            somarColuna = somarColuna + (Dados.TempoParada*Dados.NroParada );

        }

        txtTempoEfetivo_ApontaPrd.Text = Convert.ToString(somarColuna);

    }
```

> É necessário fazer `dataGridPrdMaquina_ApontPrd.Items.Count-1` pois o sistema traz uma linha em branco, caso não o faça o sistema acusa erro na hora de converter.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda...Houve um erro: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: A associação bidirecional requer Path ou XPath.

Comment: Algo com Binding acredito...E Dados.NroParada também não funcionou, ele não reconheceu como coluna.

Comment: Você criou a propriedade `NroParada` na classe `tabMaquinaParada`?

Comment: Isso...La mesmo!

Comment: O erro foi por que ele não encontrou a propriedade na classe... No código você consegue encontrar a propriedade `NroParada`?

Comment: Também não...Nem em Dados.

Comment: Estranho, eu utilizei exatamente este exemplo e funcionou aqui... Você pode postar o código  da classe `tabMaquinaParada`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40427/discussion-between-felipe-cavalcante-and-tiago-s).